# Are positrons affected by electromagnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, charge, antimatter

I know positrons are anti-electrons. But electromagnetic fields aren't matter, and are pretty good for containing high energy particles, especially in something like a stellerator. So, would it be possibly to contain positrons?

Comment: Yes they do, in fact they discovered them thanks to the fact that they interact with the electromagnetic field just like electrons with positive charge, check these links if you want to read more about their discovery: 

http://hep.uchicago.edu/cdf/frisch/p363/mmiller_positron.pdf

http://www.fisica.uniud.it/~cobal/Site/positron_discovery.pdf

Comment: got to https://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCwebsite/index.htm and hit Would you like to see a .."  and there is a positrong there turning in the magnetic field of the bubble chamber. also electron positron pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like electrons, with a positive (instead of negative) electric charge. However, if you're thinking about putting many positrons in a stellarator, remember that these devices are (more or less) good at confining plasma, which is a neutral mix of charged particles, and not electrons alone. Containing a few positrons in a vacuum is a different, and mostly unrelated, problem.